# Unmet Peer dependency warning even after installing the peer dependency

Tags: npm, redux, ionic3

I'm trying to add redux to an Ionic 3+ application. This is what I ran:

```
npm i redux @angular-redux/store flux-standard-action redux-logger --save
```

I get the following error: *UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY redux@4.0.1*
So, I then completed the following steps to try to rectify the issue:

1. rm -rf node_modules/
2. npm cache clean
3. npm install redux@4.0.1 --save

This gives me the same err: *UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY redux@4.0.1*

How can it be a dependency of itself? Something weird is going on. I've tried rearranging where in the package.json the listing falls, to no avail. Help please. Below is my package.json

---

```
{
  "name": "ionic-testing-elite-ionic",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "test": "karma start ./test-config/karma.conf.js",
    "test-ci": "karma start ./test-config/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "e2e-update": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e-test": "protractor ./test-config/protractor.conf.js",
    "e2e": "npm run e2e-update && npm run e2e-test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "flux-standard-action": "^2.0.3",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.41",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.8",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "ionic": "3.9.2",
    "jasmine": "^2.5.3",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.1.0",
    "karma": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "protractor": "^5.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I read some more into the error I was getting. The problem was that the current redux package which was being installed by default was not compatible with the version of @angular-redux/store which was being installed. There has been a major version upgrade to redux which isn't backwards compatible. I had to install redux@3.7.2 and it fixed the problem.